# How can I change the color of the code completion background in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I want to change this background:

[image: background]

in **PyCharm 2021.2**, but I can't find the appropriate style in the Settings:

[image: configuration]

Comment: If you just want to fix the light vs dark shading after changing the color scheme, restart Pycharm. If you want to customize the code scheme, see Editor > Color Scheme in settings.

Comment: Thank you @Brian .I had used the theme of Dacula, I just want to know which configuration can change the default white color of the code completion

Comment: See comments in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-59790 (links to the bug tickets). and try the solution from the last comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-59790#focus=Comments-27-5092533.0-0 (it's PhpStorm, but it should be identical in PyCharm).

Comment: It is just what i need!! Thank you @LazyOne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @LazyOne.The style is the picture as follow:
[image]

Just need to **remove the default color of the background option**
[image]